# Bug with editing to add a link to jsfiddle: error message appears even if you cancel!

Tags: bug, edits, hyperlinks, jsfiddle, cancel

A new feature on SO is that if you have a link to jsfiddle but no code, the system prevents you from posting, saying "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code"

However, this error message also appears if you start editing and add the link, but then click on Cancel to opt out of your edits!

Edit: I don't always get the error message though. It seems to depend on which answer I'm trying to edit. Need more testing.

More edit: Yes, of course the error message does not appear for answers that have one or more words backticked (which count as code. Duh).

Comment: This got nothing to do with cancel. The validation occurs in the `.blur()` event of the editor so whenever you get out of it you'll see the error message. It does not block the cancel.

Comment: Reproduced indeed. The popup even appears after the "Abandon this edit" message is acknowledged.

Comment: @Sha, it does not block the cancel, but still displays the error popup on the main page after the edit is canceled.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi can't reproduce this, the red box disappears after I cancel.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ehm, you mean you have the red error box even before you cancel? For me, it only appears after I do.

Comment: @MrLister yes. Add link to jsfiddle without code. Click anywhere outside the editor. The red box will probably pop up.

Comment: @Sha, maybe this behavior is navigator-specific. I can reproduce it on Firefox 21.0 (Windows).

Comment: For what it's worth and regarding @Sha's last comment: I reproduced this by editing an existing question and removing the code while keeping the fiddle link, which may take a different path than adding a fiddle link without code.